# PC can't recognize AzureKinectDK

Tags: windows, 3d, kinect

I want to use AzureKinectDK and tried to use it. I connected the machine to my PC, LENOVO Legion T5 28IMB05 90NC, but my PC can't recognize the machine. I checked device manager and couldn't find the machine. The machine's LED light was white and flashing, which means the device isn't connected to PC.

I use another USB port to connect my PC and the machine, but it made any sense. I tried another way to resolve it. I updated USB driver, turned off fast startup and used another PC, but I can't change the situation. Is there any way to resolve it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset it by going to Device Manager, right-clicking on "Azure Kinect Microphone Array", and select "Uninstall device". Once that is complete, detach and reattach the sensor. After that restart Azure Kinect Viewer and try again.